# IO.puts elixirs internal representation of a map

Tags: logging, elixir

I have a map `map = %{hello: :world}`

I can see elixirs internal representation of this in the console with

```
iex> IO.inspect map
%{hello: :world}
```

Is there a way to concatenate this internal representation with another string? Something like:

```
iex> IO.puts("my map is: #{to_internal_representation(map)}")
my map is %{hello: :world}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Kernel.inspect/1` returns the same string that `IO.inspect/1` prints, so you can use that:

```
IO.puts("my map is: #{inspect(map)}")
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
IO.inspect(map, label: "my map is")
=> my map is: %{hello: :world}
```

The `:label` option for `IO.inspect/2` will prefix the thing you are trying to look at.